# Get a running count by day for each client

Tags: r, sum, grouping

I have a table like:

```
ppp<-data.frame(client=c(1,1,1,3,3), 
                calldate=c('2014-08-07', '2014-08-09','2014-08-06','2014-08-07', '2014-08-08'),
                cant=c(1,2,3,2,1))
```

I need to calculate the cumulative sum of cant over days by each client.
In this case I need to get the following table:

```
client    calldate   cant   cum cant
     1  06/08/2014      3          3
     1  07/08/2014      1          4
     1  09/08/2014      2          6
     2  07/08/2014      2          2
     2  08/08/2014      1          3
```

I tried this and I got the rigth solution:

```
ppp <- ppp[order(ppp$client,ppp$calldate),]
ppp$cumsum<-unlist(tapply(ppp$cant,ppp$client,FUN=cumsum))
```

But this is the best way to do it? creating a list for each client and then unlisting the list? **Also, because I'm not specifying the date field, I only order the data instead.**

Comment: @RichardScriven, the order of dates in ppp above need to be reordered chronologically, hence the different answer.

Comment: You could also use `ave` instead of `unlist(tapply(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or a `data.table` option

```
library(data.table) # 1.9.4+
setorder(setDT(ppp), client, calldate)[, cum_cant := cumsum(cant), by = client]
ppp
#    client   calldate cant cum_cant
# 1:      1 2014-08-06    3        3
# 2:      1 2014-08-07    1        4
# 3:      1 2014-08-09    2        6
# 4:      3 2014-08-07    2        2
# 5:      3 2014-08-08    1        3
```

---

Edit: For older `data.table` versions (< 1.9.4) use `setkey` instead of `setorder`

```
setkey(setDT(ppp), client, calldate)[, cum_cant := cumsum(cant), by = client]
```

---

Edit #2 (per OPs comment):

```
setkey(setDT(ppp), client, calldate)[, `:=`(cum_cant = cumsum(cant),
                                            cummin_cant = cummin(cant)), by = client]
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks. I get an error: library(data.table) # 1.9.4+
> setorder(setDT(ppp), client, calldate)[, cum_cant := cumsum(cant), by = client]
Error: could not find function "setorder". I have the library installed as you can see when I opened it.

Comment: @GabyP, see my edit. It's would be better though if you''ll update your `data.table` package to the newest version

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that's great, can I also add another cumfun, for example cummin in the same step???

Answer (score 5):

The package `dplyr` will do this for you very easily:

```
library(dplyr) 

ppp %>% group_by(client) %>% arrange(calldate) %>% mutate(cumcant=cumsum(cant))

#client   calldate cant cumcant
#1      1 2014-08-06    3            3
#2      1 2014-08-07    1            4
#3      1 2014-08-09    2            6
#4      3 2014-08-07    2            2
#5      3 2014-08-08    1            3
```

Comment: might be better to name the result as you go (e.g. `mutate(cumsum_cant=cumsum(cant))`) so you don't end up with a non-standard column name

Answer (score 3):

Here's another base R possibility using `ave`

```
ppp$cumcant <- with(ppp, {
    ave(cant[order(client, calldate)], client, FUN = "cumsum")
})
ppp
#   client   calldate cant cumcant
# 3      1 2014-08-06    3       3
# 1      1 2014-08-07    1       4
# 2      1 2014-08-09    2       6
# 4      3 2014-08-07    2       2
# 5      3 2014-08-08    1       3
```

Comment: You must have done an `order` on `ppp` before this, otherwise you get results that don't match. Also `ave` is essentially already `split + lapply` - this reinvents the wheel a bit.